# tree navigation to show folder structure

Tags: asp.net, controls, directory

Project: ASP.NET 3.5 with C#

I have this much :- 
A table which used to store the "Folders". Each folder may contain sub folders and files. So if I click a folder, I have to list the content of the folder.

So I want to tell the user where he is now some thing like the following

Parent Folder --> Child Folder1 --> Child Folder1_1

Which ASP.NET control should I use here? How can I accomplish this task?

I think **SiteMapPath** is the best option. What you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the folder structure might be a dynamic one, so using SiteMap control is some what difficult. I will recommend you to manually do this my maintaining a ViewState/SessionState stored variable.

Update the Variable/Property when you are changing the Folder.

```
 public System.Collections.Generic.List<string> FolderPath
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["__FolderPath"] == null)
                ViewState["__FolderPath"] = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
            (System.Collections.Generic.List<string>)ViewState["__FolderPath"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["__FolderPath"] = value;
        }
    }
    public string CurrentPath
    {
        get
        {
            //retrun the current path from the List FolderPath. ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this with the TreeView control

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at the oBout TreeView which is an excellent upgrade from the Microsoft Treeview control:

http://www.obout.com/t2/index.aspx